# How to match row values across dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, dataset

I have the two following datasets:

```
dataset1
    ticker  date
0   AAPL    1/12/05
1   GOOG    1/12/05
2   GOOG    3/11/06
3   BRKA    3/11/06
4   NVDA    3/11/06
5   GME     4/8/07
6   AAPL    4/8/07
7   BRKA    4/8/07
8   GOOG    4/8/07
9   AMGN    4/8/07


dataset2
    ticker  price   date
0   AAPL    30  1/12/05
1   GOOG    24  1/12/05
2   BRKA    40  1/12/05
3   AAPL    31  3/11/06
4   GOOG    21  3/11/06
5   BRKA    32  3/11/06
6   NVDA    19  3/11/06
7   TSLA    16  3/11/06
8   AMZN    17  4/8/07
9   TSLA    30  4/8/07
10  NVDA    12  4/8/07
11  GME     26  4/8/07
12  AAPL    12  4/8/07
13  BRKA    16  4/8/07
14  GOOG    48  4/8/07
15  AMGN    36  4/8/07
```

I would like to create a third dataset which would match the tickers in both datasets with their matching dates(in dataset1) and dates(in dataset2), to finally get a third dataset that would look like this:

```
dataset3
    ticker  date    price
0   AAPL    1/12/05 30
1   GOOG    1/12/05 24
2   GOOG    3/11/06 21
3   BRKA    3/11/06 32
4   NVDA    3/11/06 19
5   GME     4/8/07  26
6   AAPL    4/8/07  12
7   BRKA    4/8/07  16
8   GOOG    4/8/07  48
9   AMGN    4/8/07  36
```

Basically I need to merge the two datasets based on several matching values in multiple columns.
I have tried a classic pd.merge but that only lets me choose one specific date, rather than match the dates across two datasets.

Thank you for your help and time. It is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems need `dataset1.mearge(dataset2)`, it is dupe.

Comment: That's not it, it just merges everything together. Notice I only want the values with matching dates but they're all different which is why I can't use `dataset1.merge(dataset2, on='date')`.

Comment: I think need `dataset1.merge(dataset2, on=['date', 'ticker'])` if more columns in both dataframes.